# Javascript filling input value

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a textfield in HTML, where the value is predefined, e.g. "hello".

Now I change the value manually on my website from "hello" to "bye". 
When I click on a button, that calls the same site again, my value of the input type should be "bye" now and not "hello". Here you can see my code :

```
<form method="POST" id="ReloadPage" name="ReloadPage" action="MyWebsite" onsubmit="getValue();">  
<strong>word: </strong>
<input id="word" type="text" size="30" value="hello" name="WORD" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue() {
  document.getElementById("word").value="bye";
}
</script>
```

But somehow, the value will always be hello and doesn't change to bye. 
Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: you can use localstorage or cookies for this. as each time the page reloads the javascript is freshly loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `function` as name of `function`.Change name of your `function`

```
<form method="POST" id="ReloadPage" name="ReloadPage" action="MyWebsite" onsubmit="return GetValue();">  
<strong>word: </strong>
<input id="word" type="text" size="30" value="hello" name="WORD" />

function GetValue() {
 document.getElementById("word").value="bye";
 return false;
}
```

Also when you `submit` the `form` page will `reload` so it will show `initial value` again.

Comment: Although what you posted is true but this wont solve the issue. page will be reloaded and entered value will be lost

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. I just named the function "function()" that it's clear for everyone. The function has another name.

Comment: @anu yes i was updating that meanwhile you commented.

Comment: @Tobias to avoid submission you can simply call function on button click.

Comment: @Leopard I've seen it and it worked! Thank you very much